# sqlalchemy load_only columns and rename the column name using label

Tags: sqlalchemy

I am trying to use the similar query mentioned below:

`session.query(User,Address).join(User.addresses).options(Load(User).load_only("name", "fullname"),Load(Address).load_only("email_addres"))`

I want to change the column names i.e., name to Name and email_address to EmailId
I got to know that I can use .label() in SqlAlchemy. But my question is: Can I use the label() in the above query ie., along with load_only(). If so, then how? if not, then what I need to use?

Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

```
session.query(User.name.label('Name'),User.fullname.label('fullname'),
Address.email_address.label('email_address')).join(Address)
```

This should give you the required columns with the desired labels.
I haven't used `load_only` in the past but I have used `with_entities` with label and it works fine. Think of label as `AS` in SQL. Hope it helps.